# libvirt java bindings. Cannot modify devices

Tags: java, libvirt

i'm planning to use libvirt to control some KVMs over the network.
So far, tha connection is working. I establish a connection with the following code

```
Connect conn = null;
    try
    {
        ConnectAuth ca = new ConnectAuthDefault();

        conn = new Connect("qemu+ssh://targetUser@targetIP/system", ca, 0);
    }
    catch(LibvirtException e)
    {
        System.out.println("exception caught:" + e);
        System.out.println(e.getError());
    }
```

and i'm getting a reference to the Domain by

```
Domain d = conn.domainLookupByName("win7");
```

But when i try to attach or detach devices (i want to modify the vnc port)

```
d.detachDevice("<graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0'/>");
```

i get an exception reading ***Requested operation is not valid: cannot detach device on inactive domain***

Ok, it seems the error message is telling me that VM is not running. So if i start the domain via

```
d.create();
```

and i execute the detachDevice from above i get the following error ***unsupported configuration: This type of device cannot be hot unplugged***.

Yeah, so what? If the Domain's not running i can't change the configuration and if it's running i can't change the config too?

Can anyone tell me please what i'm doing wrong? How do i activate a Domain without starting it? I did not find any help doing a search on the net.

Many thanks in advance for any help.
Greetings, -chris-

Answer (score 1):

you can use `virsh edit $domainName` to modify the xml configure file

Answer (score 1):

I tried that and got the same error, then I tried the `detachDeviceFlags` method and failed, too.

I think the `detachDevice` method is use to detach some sort of **hotplus** device such as a USB device. And the only way to detach a vnc graphic device is to redefine it as @liuzhijun saied.

Instead of doing it in `CLI`, here is a API-using version of mine:

```
// Assume you have got the Connect as virtConn, and Domian as dom
// I did it after the vm is shutdown
String xml = dom.getXMLDesc(0);
int[] uuid = dom.getUUID();

// I use a very simple way to erase graphic element, not recommended
// The best way to do it is to use some XML library.
xml = xml.substring(0, xml.indexOf("<graphics type='vnc'")) +
                       xml.substring(xml.indexOf("graphics>")+10);

virtCon.domainDefineXML(xml);

dom = virtCon.domainLookupByUUID(uuid);
dom.create();
```